# Printer sharing from xp to ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, windows, printing

I'm trying to share a printer from my Windows desktop (the host) to my Ubuntu desktop (the computer I'm printing from). I've seen plenty of guides that work the other way around, but how can I go from Windows to Ubuntu, not Ubuntu to Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I patched it up on my own.

**Linux Side:**

1) Install Samba

2) goto http://avasys.jp/hp/menu000000500/hpg000000442.htm

3) find your printer, and download the .deb file & the .tar.gz file and install the .deb

4) extract the .tar.gz and retrieve your .ppd file

5) copy your .ppm file into /usr/share/cups/model/

6) alt-f2 and type in "system-config-printer" and hit enter

7) hit "add"

8) network printer > windows printer via SAMBA

9) hit browse and find your printer

10) hit continue, when prompted select "Provide PPD File" and navigate to   /usr/share/cups/model/DRIVER_FILE.ppd

(you may need to install an additional 3rd party program here based on the driver and printer)

11) hit continue and fill out the information

12) hit apply, if you want, you can print a test page from here.

**Windows XP Side**

1) Open Control Panel

2) Open Printers and Faxes

3) Select the printer you want to share

4) Under the printer properties windows click on "share this printer"

**Windows 7 Side**

1) Open Control Panel

2) Open Devices and Printers

3) Select the printer you want to share

4) Under sharing tab click on "share this printer", and give it a name